# GRPC php installed, enabled in ini and works in terminal but phpinfo doesn't show enabled

Tags: php, firebase, grpc

Running on MacOS Monterey

I have installed GRPC as per: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

When I run `php --ini` the loaded config file shows as:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

And when I run the following in terminal I get `yes`:

```
sudo php -r "echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'yes' : 'no';"
```

So I know it's loaded, but when I use Firebase I get the usual error

> The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions.

So the obvious issue is that I have updated the wrong ini file, so I output `phpinfo();` but it displays the config file that matches the above:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

And right at the top of this file I have `extension="grpc.so"`

I have tried `valet restart` and can't work out why it's not accepting that GRPC is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If php has been installed with homebrew you may need to restart the php service manually as valet doesn't seem to do so.

```
brew services restart php@7.4
```

Comment: This is because of a difference between the CLI SAPI and the SAPI of the server that is in use. The CLI SAPI shows INI settings changed directly while a server needs to reload (or to restart depending on settings, a reboot of the whole computer also settles this).